# D3 filtering root data from flare.csv for treemap

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, filter

I have the following csv-formatted data saved into a variable called `csvData` and I'm trying to only show certain parts of it. The variable is formatted like so ...

```
var csvData = 'id,value
flare,
flare.analytics,
flare.analytics.cluster,
flare.analytics.cluster.AgglomerativeCluster,3938
flare.analytics.cluster.CommunityStructure,3812
flare.analytics.cluster.HierarchicalCluster,6714
flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge,743
flare.analytics.graph,
flare.analytics.graph.BetweennessCentrality,3534
flare.analytics.graph.LinkDistance,5731
flare.analytics.graph.MaxFlowMinCut,7840
flare.analytics.graph.ShortestPaths,5914
flare.analytics.graph.SpanningTree,3416
flare.analytics.optimization,
flare.analytics.optimization.AspectRatioBanker,7074
flare.animate,
flare.animate.Easing,17010
flare.animate.FunctionSequence,5842
flare.animate.interpolate,
flare.animate.interpolate.ArrayInterpolator,1983
flare.animate.interpolate.ColorInterpolator,2047
flare.animate.interpolate.DateInterpolator,1375
flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator,8746
flare.animate.interpolate.MatrixInterpolator,2202
flare.animate.interpolate.NumberInterpolator,1382
flare.animate.interpolate.ObjectInterpolator,1629
flare.animate.interpolate.PointInterpolator,1675
flare.animate.interpolate.RectangleInterpolator,2042
flare.animate.ISchedulable,1041
flare.animate.Parallel,5176
flare.animate.Pause,449
flare.animate.Scheduler,5593
flare.animate.Sequence,5534
flare.animate.Transition,9201
flare.animate.Transitioner,19975
flare.animate.TransitionEvent,1116
flare.animate.Tween,6006'
```

I am able to display all the data in a treemap by pulling it in like so ...

```
var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .parentId(function(d) {
        return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf("."));
    });

var treemap = d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .padding(1)
    .round(true);

var data = d3.csvParse(csvData, function(d) {
    return {
        id: d.id, // lowercase
        value: +d.value // lowercase
    };
});

var root = stratify(data)
    .sum(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value; });

treemap(root);
```

And then using `.data(root.leaves())` like so ...

```
d3.select("#treeChart")
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", "node")
    //... more stuff here ...
```

But that shows everything and I just want to show the `analytics` part and NOT the `animate` part. From what I gathered, I need to filter the root data but I'm not sure how to get at it. Eventually I'd like to have a pull-down that switches between `analytics` and `animate` but that becomes a second post. So I'm starting with just showing the initial `analytics` part.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `root.leaves()` you should use:

```
root.children.find( e => e.id === "flare.analytics").leaves()
```

Or

```
root.children.find( function(e) { return e.id === "flare.analytics";}).leaves()
```

That is, find the "analytics" child from root and get it leaves.

Comment: What if I can't use arrow functions? I've tried the babel translation but couldn't get it to work. 

root.children.find(function (e) {
  return e.id === "flare.analytics";
});

Comment: @Layne - I edited the answer. I had forgotten to call the leaves method. Hope this help.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about you. As soon as I can test this, I'll check it. Thanks for your help.